# Scrollbar autoscroll with specific gap

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

Sorry, I don't have any codes or markups to show you.

I just want help to get my scroll bar scroll to 10 rows down in a `ListView` when I drag the thumb button.

For a visualization just take an example of navigation home screen in Android home page. I want to implement exactly same idea in the vertical `ListView` or any `ScrollViewer` container.

Answer (score 0):

If you have focus on one item within a ListView, scrolling is automatic.

```
item.Focus();
```